# (WHY?) Greatest+Coalesce way faster than a single select with or

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I'm currently having a hard time unterstanding why this:

```
greatest(
        coalesce((select f.expReplDate from da_sakunden_fzg f where (f.ServerNr = k.ServerNr) and (k.proId = f.proId) order by f.expReplDate limit 1),0),
        coalesce((select f.expReplDate from da_sakunden_fzg f where (f.ServerNr = k.ServerNr) and (k.proId = f.ownerProId) order by f.expReplDate limit 1),0)
    ) as WMZ
```

is way faster than this:

```
(select f.expReplDate from da_sakunden_fzg f where (f.ServerNr = k.ServerNr) and ((k.proId = f.ownerProId) or (k.proId = f.proId)) order by f.expReplDate limit 1) as WMZ
```

can someone explain me why or even better is there a way to make the second one faster?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try using `explain select` for both the queries and you may have more insights/information on the query execution plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(`GREATEST` and `COALESCE` are not relevant to the real question.)

It may or may not be faster.  Here's the logic...

`OR` *usually* eliminates using an index.

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY indexed_column LIMIT 1
```

*may* be able to use `indexed_column` to find the `1` row you want with no extra effort.  But it you throw an `OR` into the formula, it *may* need to scan the table to do the `OR`, then sort the results, and finally do `LIMIT 1` -- a lot more work.

In your case, you probably have `INDEX(ServerNr, proId, expReplDate)`, which is the perfect index for each of the non-OR subqueries, but not nearly as useful for the OR case.

Look at the `EXPLAIN` -- you will see a difference that clumsily says what I said.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...` says it better.

Without the 'perfect' index, the `OR` could have been faster.